# Calculate the sum of the child objects of the parent entities in the list

Tags: c#, list, sum, parentid

My list is structured like this:

```
public class Custo{
      public int id { get; set; }
      public int idParent { get; set; }
      public decimal amount{ get; set; }
      public decimal unitaryValue{ get; set; }

}

List<Custo> myLIst  = new List<Custo>();
```

I want my list to return like this:

```
Name              Total Amount      Total Value

Projetos           17,00            $70 

  Arquitetura      15,00            $60

    Estrutura      10,00            $35
    Modulo          5,00            $25

  Desenho           2,00            $10  
    Artistico       2,00            $10  

Projetos Eletricos  0,00            $0
```

Comment: Lookup the composite design pattern.
http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/composite-design-pattern-dotnet

Comment: You need to join the class with the parent classes so you can get the project name (not the id) and you need a list of the projects (not just the Custo class).

Comment: How is `Custo` related to `Projetos`? May each project have many `Custos`?

Comment: Did you try anything or just want your work to be done by others?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially in a composite pattern you would need three classes. One would be the treenode and the other two would inherit from that. One would be a project capable of holding children. The other would be a child/leaf node and would be the individual Custos.

When you use the classes you would create a new Projectos and add child nodes, then call the Display method when you wanted them to display. You could obviously add logic for other functions. This is similar to code found here: http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern

Usage might be
**Main**

```
Projectos project = new Projectos("Projetos");
project.Add(new Custos("Arquitetura", 15, 70.00);

Projectos electricos = new Projectos("Electricos");
electricos.Add(new Custos("custo1", 20, 80.00);
project.Add(electricos);

project.Display();
```

**Projectos**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CompositePatternExercise
{
    class Projectos : CustosNode
    {
        private List<CustosNode> elements = new List<CustosNode>();

        // Constructor
        public Projectos(string name) : base(name)
        {
        }

        public override void Add(CustosNode d)
        {
            elements.Add(d);
        }

        public override void Remove(CustosNode d)
        {
            elements.Remove(d);
        }
        public override void Display()
        {
            decimal totalValue = 0;
            decimal totalAmount = 0;

            Console.WriteLine(_name);

            // Display each child element on this node
            foreach (CustosNode d in elements)
            {
                d.Display();
                totalAmount += d.Amount;
                totalValue += d.Value;
            }

            Console.Write("Project total:" + totalAmount.ToString("C") + " " + totalAmount.ToString("C"));

        }
    }
}
```

**Custos**

```
namespace CompositePatternExercise
{
    class Custos : CustosNode
    {
            // Constructor
            public Custos(string name, decimal amount, decimal value) : base(name, amount, value)
            {
            }
            public override void Add(CustosNode c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                  "Cannot add to a custo");
            }
            public override void Remove(CustosNode c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                  "Cannot remove from a custo");
            }
            public override void Display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_name + " " + Amount.ToString("C") + " " + Value.ToString("C"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CustosNode**

```
namespace CompositePatternExercise
{
    abstract class CustosNode
    {
        protected string _name;
        protected decimal _amount = 0m;
        protected decimal _value = 0m;

        public decimal Value { get => _value; }
        public decimal Amount { get => _amount; }

        // Constructor
        public CustosNode(string name)
        {
            this._name = name;
        }
        public CustosNode(string name, decimal amount, decimal value)
        {
            this._name = name;
            this._amount = amount;
            this._value = value;
        }
        public abstract void Add(CustosNode c);
        public abstract void Remove(CustosNode c);
        public abstract void Display();
    }
}
```